# How to find a data in CSV file with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem , i wanna to search a data with python from csv file

my code like this

```
#search process area
area_proses = []
sg1 = []
sg2 = []
sg3 = []
avg = []

#input number you want to search
number = raw_input('Masukan id Spesific Goal\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('C:/xampp_2/htdocs/SkripsiV2/fuzzy/download.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")

#loop through csv list
for row in csv_file:
    area_proses.append(row[1])
    sg1.append(row[2])
    sg2.append(row[3])
    sg3.append(row[4])
    avg.append(row[5])
    #if current rows 1nd value is equal to input, print that row
    if number == row[0]:
        #masukan data
         print(area_proses,sg1,sg2,sg3,avg)
```

my problem is when i search with id 11 the output is like this:

```
(['area_proses', 'Service Delivery'], ['sg1', '3.71'], ['sg2', '3.48'], ['sg3',
'3.30'], ['avg', '3.50'])
```

but when i search id 12 the output is like :

```
 (['area_proses', 'Service Delivery', 'Incident Resolution and Prevention'], ['sg
    1', '3.71', '3.83'], ['sg2', '3.48', '3.65'], ['sg3', '3.30', '3.70'], ['avg', '
    3.50', '3.73'])
```

How i can solved this problem?

Download.csv

```
"id","area_proses","sg1","sg2","sg3","avg","fuzzy",
"11","Service Delivery","3.71","3.48","3.30","3.50","0.00000000000",
"12","Incident Resolution and Prevention","3.83","3.65","3.70","3.73","0.00000000000",
"13","Service System Development","3.93","3.29","3.26","3.49","0.00000000000",
"14","Service System Transition","3.00","3.43","0.00","3.22","0.00000000000",
"15","Strategic Service Management","3.48","3.86","0.00","3.67","0.00000000000",
"16","Configuration Management","3.14","3.57","0.00","3.36","0.00000000000",
"17","Measurement and Analysis","2.93","3.18","0.00","3.06","0.00000000000",
```

Comment: please post a sample of the content in `download.csv`

Comment: Why don't you import this as a pandas Dataframe and work on that?

Comment: @VanPeer i have add a sample from download.csv

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pandas library. Install it, then do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')

df[df['id'] == number]
```

Comment: Corrected it. Earlier I had referenced `df[0]`, but this is called `df['id']` since your columns have names now.

Answer (score 0):

Just change 'rb' to 'r'

```
fopn = open(file_loc, "r")
   csv_file = csv.reader(fopn)
   for row in csv_file:
       if number == row[0]:
          print(row)
```